# New to nUnit, getting error ... "is not accessible in this context because it is 'Public'"

Tags: vb.net, access-modifiers, nunit-3.0

I have written the following code as my first test in nUnit.

```
Public Class Tests

    <TestFixture()>
      Private Class TranslationTest

          <Test()>
          Private Sub LanguageTest()
            Dim stringToTest As String = "Tower Count"

            strLanguageText(stringToTest, LanguageIDs.English, 0)
            Assert.Equals("Tower Count")


          End Sub
      End Class
    End Class
```

Intellisense is saying that both the strLanguageText method and the LanguageIDs.Enlish enum are "not accessible in this context because it is 'Public'". I can understand something not being accessible because its modifier is Private, but why would having a modifier of Public prevent it from being accessible by the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the error said "Public" when I looked at the Method being tested its modifier was Friend. When I assigned my test to the same namespace as the methods being tested it worked.

**Update:** According to O'Reilly's [C# & VB.NET Conversion Pocket Reference](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003197.do), "Outer Classes at the IL level have only two possible scopes: private or public."

My amature guess is that this is why the error was reporting as 'Public'.